# Three calculators work in different way when I calculate: 50 + 10% * 20%

Tags: percentages, calculator

I've been working on developing simple calculator and currently working on order of operations for percent symbols.
So when I trying the following equation, three different calculators show different results.

> 50 + 10% * 20% =

- Apple iPhone calculator: 51
- Apple macOS widget calculator: 55
- Google web calculator: 11

Who result is the right and what calculator behaviour should I stick?

[image]

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: I think the various systems are just guessing (poorly) at interpretations.  I note that [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50%2B10%25) evaluates $50+10\%$ as $55$, apparently "reasoning" that you are asking for "$50$ plus $10\%$ of $50$.  I'd call that an eccentric reading, though it does get you to the $11$.  If I were forced to assign meaning to your expression, I'd rewrite it as $50+(.1\times .2)=50.02$ but I am not surprised to see that none of the calculators agree with that.

Comment: If you are trying to find expressions that machines can't parse, then mission accomplished.  If you had a meaning in mind for the expression...what was it?

Comment: Should have added:  [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50%2B10%25*20%25) actually gives two computations.  The primary one is $11$, for (I believe) the reasons I explained.  But it also gives a "decimal interpretation" which comes to $\left( 50 +\frac {10}{100}\right)\times \frac {20}{100}=10.02$, so there's a new value for you.

Comment: just trying to understand what result I should display user when he type symbols in exact sequence I described in post above. Please note that I want to support order of calculations

Comment: @Sergio the safest (and I think most standard) interpretation is the one that lulu made above and that I did in my answer, which yields $50.02$. It seems that some of these other calculators have predicted that some people won't use percentages right and have written their own algorithms to "guess" what people mean when they try something that looks erroneous. Don't be fooled, though; $50+10\%$ would never be calculated as $55$ in any mathematics classroom; I would probably not try to mimic their approach unless you had a really good reason to do so.

Comment: I (and I think most if not everyone from a mathematics background) basically just see the $\%$ symbol in this context as interchangeable with the number $\frac{1}{100}$. That is, $50\% = 50 \times \frac{1}{100} = 0.5$. Of course, you should prioritise this multiplication before any addition unless otherwise bracketed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a scientific calculator, it probably won't do the standard order of operations for you, and will instead just do things in left-to-right order as you enter them.

Consider that $10\%=0.1$ and $20\% = 0.2$. Then $50 + (20\%)(10\%) = 50 + (0.1)(0.2) = 50 + 0.02 = 50.02$

In saying this, I do wonder what it is exactly that you're trying to calculate; I can't think of any purpose one might ever need to perform the calculation $50 + 10\% \cdot 20\%$, so I fear that you may be trying to calculate something incorrectly.

For example, if you've got $n$ things and want to add an *extra* $50\%$ *of them*, then the expression should *not* be $n+50\%$, it should be $n (150\%)$. It could be that you're entering the wrong expression for the problem you're trying to solve.

Edit: Also I should note that the Google online calculator had the same interpretation as me and yields $50.02$ as an answer, unlike the value of $11$ you assert in your question. I'm not sure how you entered the question to get 11.

[image: Google calculator answer]

Comment: added screen shot to first topic

Comment: P.S. please note that I don't use any brackets

Answer (score 0):

My guess is as follows:

Google search bar =50.02 because it only accesses knowledge about PEMDAS getting the multiplication back as 0.02 which it then adds to 50.

Google Calculator on search results page= 11 because it likely interprets it as (50+10%*50)*20% or 55 over 5. Percents are of something.

Apple iphone probably interprets it as 50+(0.02*50)

Apple macOS widget, probably thinks the second percent doesn't make sense and ignores it , or was built for 2 operand expressions only.

Without meaning known ahead of time, All they can do is guess. All math is based on logical inference. definitions matter.